# javascript : trim all properties of an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to trim all properties of an object? In other words, can I change that:

```
{a: ' a', b: 'b ', c: ' c '}
```

To this:

```
{a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
```

It seems I can't map an object, so how can I apply a function to all properties an get the object back?

Comment: While that doesn't answer the exact, narrow, question posed; I would say that it should be very easy to get to a solution following the answer posted there.

Comment: dose it need to be deep also?

Comment: think this might be the closest thing to map an deep object `JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => typeof v === 'string' ? v.trim() : v)`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use **[`Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** to iterate the object properties and update its values:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = obj[k].trim());
```

**Demo:**

```js
var obj = {
  a: ' a',
  b: 'b ',
  c: ' c '
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = obj[k].trim());
console.log(obj);
```

**Edit:**

If your `object` values can be of other data `types`(not only `strings`), you can add a check to avoid calling `.trim()` on non `strings`.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = typeof obj[k] == 'string' ? obj[k].trim() : obj[k]);
```

```js
var obj = {
  a: ' a',
  b: 'b ',
  c: ' c ',
  d: 500
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = typeof obj[k] == 'string' ? obj[k].trim() : obj[k]);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: `forEach` would be preferable over `map`.

Comment: @photo Why would it be? `.map` is designed for such things.

Comment: Because `map` is used to return a new transformed array. Here we're just need to loop through and modify the `obj`.

Comment: This don't work if object contains object attributes

Comment: @maroodb this portion of code were dedicated for the OP code, which contains only `string` values, in the first place, but we can change it to avoid such thing. I made an edit.

Comment: @pymarco I observe that .map is faster than .forEach, make me correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @pymarco No you are not wrong, [`.map()` is a little bit faster than `.foreach`](https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c#221d), but `for`loops are always faster :)

Comment: I would suggest using forEach instead of map, because its purpose not to return an array, but to change object properties. By doing that you would avoid "Code Smells"

Comment: @D0mm Fair enough, I edited my answer to use `.forEach()` as it was recommended and as we will just edit the original `array`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Object.keys` to reduce and trim the values, it'd look something like this:

```js
function trimObjValues(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = obj[curr].trim()
    return acc;
  }, {});
}


const ex = {a: ' a', b: ' b', c: ' c'};
console.log(trimObjValues(ex));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by looping through it.

```
for(var key in myObject) {
    myObject[key] = myObject[key].trim();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to watch out for this because `for...in` will go up the prototype chain and iterate over all those properties too

Comment: This can fail with on non-string objects without a trim function. Add a sanity check `if (typeof parsed_pg_request[key] == 'string') {}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a use reduce to create an object with the values you're looking for:

```js
const test = {a: ' a', b: 'b ', c: ' c '}
const trimAllValues = input => Object.keys(input)
  .reduce((prev, next) =>
    Object.assign(prev, {
      [next]: test[next].replace(/\s+/g, '')
    }), {});
  
const result = trimAllValues(test)
console.log(result)
```

Lodash's [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapValues) will be more performant and have better browser support. You can either use lodash, or alternatively [have a look at their source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/mapValue.js) and implement the same:

```
function mapValue(object, iteratee) {
  object = Object(object)
  const result = {}

  Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
    result[key] = iteratee(object[key], key, object)
  })
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const object1 = {
  a: ' somestring',
  b: ' a',
  c: 'a '
};

const newVals = Object.values(object1).map(val => val.trim());
console.log(newVals); //["somestring", "a", "a"]
```