# JavaScript trim all own property key names of an object?

Tags: javascript, properties, trim

How to trim all **own ([not inherited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)) property keys / names** of an object? To trim the key name, not the property's value.

PS. Closest similar question I found is about trimming **property values**: [javascript : trim all properties of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616152/javascript-trim-all-properties-of-an-object)

EDIT: This question was suggested as a possible duplicate. However, I'm **explicitly needing to trim just the key name, not the value**: [Trim white spaces in both Object key and value recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510625/trim-white-spaces-in-both-object-key-and-value-recursively)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim white spaces in both Object key and value recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510625/trim-white-spaces-in-both-object-key-and-value-recursively)

Comment: This question is about trimming just the key name, not the value. However thanks for linking that question as it has some helpful approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understood, `Object.keys()` or `Object.entries()` should do the job.

```js
const obj = { "a " : 1 , "   b " : 2 };

const trimmed = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let [key, value] = curr;
  // Checking if the key is a string
  acc[typeof key === "string" ? key.trim() : key] = value; 
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(trimmed); // -> { a: 1, b: 2 } notice the trimmed keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the key is a string (and not [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)) and trim this value and get a new object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const
    obj = { "a " : 1 , "   b " : 2 },
    trimmed = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [
        typeof k === 'string' ? k.trim() : k,
        v
    ]));

console.log(trimmed);
```